# Jetpack Paging 3.0 with Airbnb/epoxy only load the first page

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-paging-3, epoxy

I am trying to use Jetpack Paging 3.0 to get all the characters in Rick and Morty API using retrofit and display it using Airbnb/epoxy. But I only get the first page I've spent several hours trying to look for a solution but no luck.

**Link to API**
([Rick and Morty API](https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#get-all-characters))

**CODE:**

**[1](https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#get-all-characters) Retrofit**

```
@GET("character/")
suspend fun getAllCharactersByPage(
    @Query("page") pageIndex : Int
): Response<GetAllCharactersByPageResponse>
```

**[2] Paging Source**

```
class AllCharacterPagingSource(
private val repository: AllCharactersRepository) : PagingSource<Int, Character>() {
override suspend fun load(
    params: LoadParams<Int>
): LoadResult<Int, Character> {

    val pageNumber = params.key ?: 1
    val prevKey = if (pageNumber == 1) null else pageNumber + 1

    val response = NetworkLayer.apiClient.getAllCharactersByPage(pageNumber)
    response.getException?.let {
      return LoadResult.Error(it)
    }

    return LoadResult.Page(
        data = response.body.results.map { CharacterMapper.buildFrom(it) },
        prevKey = prevKey,
        nextKey = getPageIndexFromNext(response.body.info.next)
    )
}

override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Character>): Int? {
    return state.anchorPosition?.let {
        state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
            ?: state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
    }
}

private fun getPageIndexFromNext(next: String?): Int?{
    return next?.split("?page=")?.get(1)?.toInt()
}
```

}

**[3] View Model (Pager)**

```
class AllCharactersViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val repository = AllCharactersRepository()

val flow = Pager(
    PagingConfig(Constants.PAGE_SIZE, Constants.PREFETCH_SIZE, enablePlaceholders = false)
) {
    AllCharacterPagingSource(repository)
}.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

}

**[4] Fragment (Submitting data)**

```
iewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        allCharactersViewModel.flow.collectLatest {
            pagingEpoxyController.submitData(it)
        }
    }

    binding.charactersEpoxyRecyclerView.setController(pagingEpoxyController)
```

**[5] Epoxy Controller**

```
class CharactersPagingEpoxyController :  PagingDataEpoxyController<Character>() {

var context : Context? = null

override fun buildItemModel(currentPosition: Int, item: Character?): EpoxyModel<*> {
    return CharacterCardModel(
            character = item!!,
            context = context!!,
            onClick = { characterId ->
            }
        ).id("characters_${item.id}")
    }



data class CharacterCardModel(
    val character : Character,
    val context : Context,
    val onClick: (Int) -> Unit
) : ViewBindingKotlinModel<CharacterCardContainerModelBinding>(R.layout.character_card_container_model) {
    override fun CharacterCardContainerModelBinding.bind() {
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(character.image)
            .into(imageView)

        characterName.text = character.name
        mirroredCharacterName.text = character.name

    }
}
```

}

**Thanks in advance!!!**

Comment: What is the value of `Constants.PAGE_SIZE`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess prevKey should be something like this

`val previewPage= if (pageNumber ==1 ) null else pageNumber -1`